# Failed to install web app extension Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

trying to install Application Insights extension on azure web service 
it gives following error in portal

> Failed to install web app extension Application Insights to install
>   web app extension Application Insights. Heuristics indicate
>   WebApiClient request timed out. Uri:
>   https://XXXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/api/siteextensions/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites
>   Timeout: 00:01:00

still it shows that extension is installed in the extension list. 
but app does not works it gives `Service Unavailable
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.`

details error json is

```
{
"authorization": null,
"caller": null,
"channels": null,
"claims": {},
"correlationId": null,
"description": "Failed to install web app extension Application Insights. Heuristics indicate WebApiClient request timed out. Uri: https://SITENAME.p.azurewebsites.net/api/siteextensions/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites\r\nTimeout: 00:01:00",
"eventDataId": null,
"eventName": null,
"eventSource": null,
"category": null,
"eventTimestamp": "Sun Jun 25 2017 11:28:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
"id": "Web app extension installation failed_Sun Jun 25 2017 11:28:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
"level": "1",
"operationId": null,
"operationName": {
    "value": "Web app extension installation failed",
    "localizedValue": "Web app extension installation failed"
},
"resourceGroupName": null,
"resourceProviderName": null,
"resourceType": null,
"resourceId": null,
"status": {
    "value": "Error",
    "localizedValue": "Error"
},
"subStatus": null,
"submissionTimestamp": null,
"subscriptionId": null,
"properties": {
    "correlationIds": "08c0d87b-0208-4896-8423-5c332176b0c4"
},
"relatedEvents": []
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Application Insights enablement experience has changed for Azure App Services. You don't need to install the extension, you can use the Azure Portal as explained in these [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps).

Answer (score 0):

> still it shows that extension is installed in the extension list. but app does not works it gives Service Unavailable
>   HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

According to your description, I assumed that you could click "DEVELOPMENT TOOLS > Extensions" under your app service, click Application Insights, then click "Delete" button and re-install the Application Insights extension. Also, you could leverage **Site extensions** under [kudu service](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-the-kudu-service) by access `https://{your-app-name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/SiteExtensions/#gallery`, then install your extension.

Additionally, you could create a new website and install the extension via Azure Portal for isolating this issue. Also, you could integrate application insights into your project and deploy to azure app service. For more details, you could refer to [ApplicationInsights-Home](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home).